# php static variable inside function

Tags: php

PHP [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) states the following:

> Another important feature of variable scoping is the static variable.
>   A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does
>   not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

My code:

```
function keeptrack() {
    static $count = 0;
    $count += $count + 1;
    echo $count;

}

keeptrack();
keeptrack();
keeptrack();
```

Output: `137`

Why does it not output `123`

Comment: `static $count = 0; echo ++$count;` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why is because with += what was going on was `$count = $count + $count + 1`

Answer (score 3):

You're not adding `1` to `$count`, you're adding the current value of `$count` plus `1`.

```
$count += $count + 1;
```

What you probably intended:

```
$count = $count + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry it's a little late and I was tired. You are correct in your logic. What I really meant though was `$count += 1` lol